# Changing the name and the name appearing in the TOC of my list of references

Tags: bibtex

I would like to change the name of my list of references from "References" to "Bibliography". In addition, I would like to have a different name appearing in the table of contents (instead of "Bibliography", I'd like to have "Part 3: Bibliography"). I am using the document class `article` and work with BibTeX.

What I managed so far was to change the name of my list of references using `\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}`. But how can I change the name that appears in the TOC? I tried `\renewcommand{\refname}{[Part 3: Bibliography]{Bibliography}}` but that didn't work.

Edit: I have something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{General Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Part I: General Introduction} 
Text

\section*{Papers}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Part II: Papers}

\section{Paper 1}
Text

\section{Paper 2}
Text

\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Provide a Minimum Working Environment, please.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on which packages you are using. If you use biblatex, you can simply make a new chapter/section named Part 3: Bibliography and implement your Bibliography with `\printbibliography[heading=none]`. A MWE would look like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sample}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{General Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Part I: General Introduction} 
Text

\section*{Papers}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Part II: Papers}

\section{Paper 1}
Text

\section{Paper 2}
Text

\section*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Part III: Bibliography}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Using BibTeX you can first redefine the name of the bibliography using `\usepackage[english]{babel}` and `\addto{\captionsenglish}{\renewcommand{\refname}{Part III: Bibliography}}`. This will then be shown in the TOC. Now you can disable the title of the bibliography at the position where you want to put it and simply open up a new section with `\section*{Bibliography}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{\renewcommand{\refname}{Part III: Bibliography}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{General Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Part I: General Introduction}
Text

\section*{Papers}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Part II: Papers}

\section{Paper 1}
Text

\section{Paper 2}
Text

\section*{Bibliography}

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
\bibliography{bib}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

This gives you:

[image]

Comment: I am using apacite. I tried removing the name using `\renewcommand{\refname}{}` and then manually adding a new title with `\section[Part 3: Bibliography]{Bibliography}` but then the bibliography appeared twice (2 rows) in the TOC, once without any name and once with the name I specified in the brackets.

Comment: I just edited my answer to include a solution using BibTeX

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because `\captionsenglish` isn't known. Nothing is added to the TOC. Inspired by your first answer, I found a way (apacite-specific though) that worked: when loading the package, I added the option `\usepackage[notocbib]{apacite}` so that nothing is added to the TOC and then I renamed the title using `\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}`and added `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Part III: Bibliography}`to add the desired title to the TOC.